# How to join two models by id (without ForeignKey) and sort by linked model fields in admin

Tags: python, django, join, django-models, django-admin

I have a problem with joining two django models in django admin.

What I have and what can't I change?
(of course this is a changed shortcut of what I really have)

```
class Thing(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()

class ThingRelation(models.Model):
    related_thing1 = models.IntegerField()
    related_thing2 = models.IntegerField()
```

Where `related_thing` is a relation to `Thing.id`.

Now I have Django admin:

```
class ThingRelationAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('related_thing1', 'related_thing1_name', 'related_thing2', 'related_thing2_name')

    def related_thing1_name(self, obj):
        try:
            thing = Thing.objects.get(id=obj.related_thing1)
        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            return ''
        return thing.name

    def related_thing2_name(self, obj):
        try:
            thing = Thing.objects.get(id=obj.related_thing2)
        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            return ''
        return thing.name
```

Now to the point. Everything so far works fine. But what I really want right now is to have the `_name` columns sortable. I do know, that this would be impossible, if the functional columns would be totally disconnected from models itselves, but in this situation I guess that must be somehow possible. I've spent some time trying to achieve joining ThingRelation with Thing, but maybe there's some other way.

And I can't simply change IntegerField into ForeignKey.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display) says you can add an `admin_order_field` attribute to the method itself which represents the field to sort on. Not sure if that works with related models though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to override `ModelAdmin` `queryset` method to add fields to query (by using queryset [`extra`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.extra) method) on which you can sort and then use `admin_order_field` attribute:

```
class ThingRelationAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('related_thing1', 'related_thing1_name',
                    'related_thing2', 'related_thing2_name')

    def queryset(self, request):
        qs = super(ThingRelationAdmin, self).queryset(request)
        # change appname to your application name in which this models placed
        qs = qs.extra(
            select = {
                'rt1name': 't1.name',
                'rt2name': 't2.name'
            },
            tables=['"appname_thing" as "t1"', '"appname_thing" as "t2"'],
            where=['appname_thingrelation.related_thing1=t1.id',
                   'appname_thingrelation.related_thing2=t2.id']
        )
        return qs

    def related_thing1_name(self, obj):
        return obj.rt1name

    def related_thing2_name(self, obj):
        return obj.rt2name

    related_thing1_name.admin_order_field = 'rt1name'
    related_thing2_name.admin_order_field = 'rt2name'
```

Comment: Works perfectly fine after one little fix. I had to use ` instead of " in extra tables.

Comment: @Gandi what db do you use?

Comment: MySQL, probably that's why.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at Django Many-to-one relationship model? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/

Comment: Yes - let me quote myself: "And I can't simply change IntegerField into ForeignKey." ;) I'm looking for a way to achieve o ForeignKey-like relation effect with having only an IntegerField in model. And I need it only in ModelAdmin.

Comment: Ah, sorry, didn't catch that.